# replace function in dml statements in oracle 8i

Tags: oracle

Can we use `Replace()` function in an update statement ? 
If yes then how?

I have a column `enrollno` having values like '800-00001' to '800-01800'.
I want to replace initial '800-' to '800' in all 1800 records. 
(Output should be '8000001' to '80001800')

Is it possible through replace function or any other option is there in ORACLE8i ?

MaheshA...

Comment: You are still using Oracle 8i? That release is more than 10 years old.

Answer (score 2):

```
update table set col = replace(col,'800-','800')
```